# How to hide PDFTron popup in Objective C

Tags: swift, objective-c, pdf, pdftron

[image]

I am trying to disable this feature in default PDFtron library.

I tried a lot and not at all disable this item. If anyone knows how to disable it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide more context.  How are you using it in your code? What ways have you tried to resolve it, and what was the outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the behavior of the popup menu with the following `PTToolManagerDelegate` method: [toolManager(_:, shouldShowMenu:, forAnnotation:, onPageNumber:)](https://docs.apryse.com/api/ios/Protocols/PTToolManagerDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)PTToolManagerDelegate(im)toolManager:shouldShowMenu:forAnnotation:onPageNumber:). You would want to return `false` from the method to disable the menu from appearing.

Note that if you are using a `PTDocumentController` to show the document, then you will need to create a subclass and override that method:

```swift
class CustomDocumentController : PTDocumentController {
    
    override func toolManager(_ toolManager: PTToolManager,
                              shouldShowMenu menuController: UIMenuController,
                              forAnnotation annotation: PTAnnot?,
                              onPageNumber pageNumber: UInt) -> Bool {
        // Uncomment to disable popup menu in all scenarios.
        // return false
        
        if annotation == nil {
            // No annotation is selected.
            if toolManager.tool as? PTPanTool != nil {
                // This is the long-press menu over blank space in the document.
                
                // Uncomment to disable long-press menu.
                // return false
            } else if toolManager.tool as? PTTextSelectTool != nil {
                // This is the text-selection menu shown for selected text.
                
                // Disable text-selection menu.
                return false
            }
        }
        
        // Use default menu behavior from superclass.
        return super.toolManager(toolManager,
                                 shouldShowMenu: menuController,
                                 forAnnotation: annotation,
                                 onPageNumber: pageNumber)
    }
    
}
```

The code above will disable the text-selection menu, but leave the long-press (over blank space) and annotation-selection menus enabled. You can uncomment the commented-out lines to control those menus as well if you want.